# How to set up reftex-view-crossref-extra in Emacs ?

Tags: regex, emacs, pattern-matching, org-mode

The expression `reftex-view-crossref-extra` sets additional patterns for `reftex-view-crossref` function. It consists of Macro Regexp, Search Regexp and Highlight Group(as illustrated below):

> (MACRO-RE SEARCH-RE HIGHLIGHT).
>
> MACRO-RE is matched against the macro.  SEARCH-RE is the regexp
>   used to search for cross references.  `%s' in this regexp is replaced
>   with with the macro argument at point.  HIGHLIGHT is an integer
>   indicating which subgroup of the match should be highlighted.

I'm trying to match the following pattern (org-mode footnotes):

```
[fn:author2000title:Optional text]
```

`author2000title` is the biblatex label that i want to have a match for. How can i write `MACRO-RE` and `SEARCH-RE`, such that  `reftex-view-crossref` works on these kind of records?

Comment: Do you want to catch the whole `[fn:author2000title:Optional text]` or just `author2000title`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you find a solution for your special setup. To test this, I setup a small org testfile

```
* Heading 1
  \oinc{mylabel}
   stuff
* Heading 2
  otherstuff [fn:mylabel:Display text]
```

Setting `reftex-view-crossref-extra` to

```
(setq reftex-view-crossref-extra '(("\\\\oinc" "\\[fn:%s:[^]]*?\\]" 0)))
```

if I place point at `\oinc{mylabel}`, inside the braces, and press `C-c &`, `[fn...]` gets highlighted and identified as first and only match.

**Edit**: Replace `"\\\\oinc"` with a regex holding the label defining macros you use, e.g. `"\\\\mylabel\\|\\\\oinc"`. You can't define reference matches for the standard commands `\label`, etc.; their handling is hardcoded; but you can define a new command aliasing the standard¹, and using this to define your labels can use `reftex-view-crossref` setup the way shown here to search for your custom references.

To summarize: `MACRO-RE` is a regexp matching the macros without parameters you are interested in, `SEARCH-RE` is a regexp that matches your desired reference format, and in which you should place a `%s` that will be replaced by the argument to the macro matched with `MATCH-RE`. If your `SEARCH-RE` contains capturing parentheses, you can highlight the part of the capturing matches only, by providing the third list element `HIGHLIGHT` as integer referring to the capturing parens as ususal for regex, i.e. `0` for the whole match, `1` for the first capture, `2` for the second etc., where the order of opening parens defines the numbering of the captured matches.

kind regards,
Tom

1: `\newcommand{\mylabel}[1]{\label{#1}}`

Nota Bene: If you want only `mylabel` to be highlighted on search/matching, change that to

```
(setq reftex-view-crossref-extra '(("\\oinc" "\\[fn:\\(%s\\):[^]]*?\\]" 1)))
```

notice the matching parens in `SEARCH-RE`, the second element in the list.